# Rename photos based on a specific field in the data layer

Tags: pyqgis, photos, rename

I have an address layer, and I also take photographs associated with the address points. The image name is in the photo field of the layer however I want to rename the actual photograph to the value in the address field I need to use PyQGIS to rename the photos based on the address layers.

Comment: Unless you try something, add the code attempt to your question, and tell us what the problem is your question will probably get closed. My answer should help you to get started

Answer (score 1):

1. [Accessing attributes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#accessing-attributes)
2. [How to rename a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)